# Get List of all Preference Pages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, pde

Does anyone know how to receive a List of all entries of "Preferences" and "Properties" programmatically. 
I do know about `PreferencesUtil`, but this only allows me to open a specific page by id (as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PreferenceManager` to get the preference pages:

```
PreferenceManager prefsManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager();

IPreferenceNode [] rootNodes = prefsManager.getRootSubNodes();
```

Each `IPreferenceNode` can have children so you must call `getSubNodes()` on each node to get these.

There is no equivalent for property pages. These are managed by `PropertyPagesRegistryReader` which is an **internal** class and therefore is not usable.

Alternatively you can use the extension registry to read the extension points yourself. So something like:

```
IExtensionRegistry extReg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();

IExtensionPoint extPoint = extReg.getExtensionPoint("org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages");

IConfigurationElement [] elements = extPoint.getConfigurationElements();
```

which gives you all the `IConfigurationElement` for an extension point.